# Не запускается сервер (Openserver)

Tags: php, apache, сервер, openserver

При установленном Apache 2.2 и PHP 5.2 работает, при установке PHP более поздней версии не запускается (со всеми версиями Apache) ps Windows 10 x64

лог:

> 2019-06-04 12:37:34  Не удалось запустить Apache_2.2-PHP_5.2-5.4
>
> 2019-06-04 12:37:34  Не удалось запустить MySQL-5.5-x64
>
> 2019-06-04 12:37:34  Сбой запуска!

Comment: Что за сервер используете?

Comment: использую openserver

Comment: запустите OS от администратора

Comment: тоже самое ни денвер не запускается ни он

Comment: переключаюсь на php 5.3 и все ппц

Comment: @Григорий логи посмотрите.
Как переключаетесь?

Comment: в модулях выставляю apache 2.2 который как влогах написано должен работать с php 5.2-5.4 если, там же в модулях стоит php 5.2 то работает если 5.3 и выше нет, apache переключал на все версии которые есть в программе результат тот же не работает

Comment: Используйте apache 2.4 x64 с php 5.3, а, вообще, пора бы php 7+ использовать, нет? А вместе и с этим перейти с apache на nginx пора бы

Comment: пробовал все возможные конфигурации в этой программе, и php 7 и опять же со всеми apache в общем все, работает только 5.2, мне минимум 5.3 надо

Comment: `OSPanel/userdata/logs` - логи сервера, найдите там лог apache и посмотрите что за ошибка

Comment: apache нет лога только main и базы данных

Comment: `Windows 10` та ещё беспросветная дыра. Поверьте все пути установки - они должны быть без пробелов в названии, отключите в настройках сервера  виртуальный диск, запустите от имени администратора, сбросьте настройки по дефолту, запустите сервер в отладочном режиме - `самый разумный вариант`.